# CURL POSTFIELD pass value in id or name?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I now write a simple login by using curl to grab information for customization login from a site.

```
$url2="https://192.168.1.4/j_security_check";
$PostData = "user=abc&password=123";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $PostData);
```

I would like to use the above code for pass the data to j_security_check page.

The problem I want to ask is...when the data pass to other page, it will pass by id or the name of such input type? (textbox field) ??

In this case, 'user' and 'password' are both textbox id. The name of textbox is 'j_user' and 'j_password'.

In addition, I have tried to pass both id and name, but both are not success and return me fail in login. I ensured that login name and password are both correct.

My approach is pass the login name and password to the authentication page (j_security_check) and after that it will auto confirm the login name and password then logged in.

Are there any mistake in my approach or consideration since i am really new in curl?

Thanks everybody so much!!

Comment: Are you trying to get `j_security_check` to actually log the user in? Because that won't work. Your script will need to read the response from `j_security_check` and log the user in, or not, depending on the response.

Comment: Try to look for an HTML "form" tag in the page source. Then cURL to the URL in the "action" attribute if you can find it, since that would be the script that accepts the posts and gets.

Comment: thanks for reply, in the login page, the code is something like this: <form method="POST" action="j_security_check">

Comment: I got this error after i modify back into j_user and j_password. 
404 Not Found
The requested URL /error.jsp was not found on this server

Comment: Actually, the address (192.168.1.4) is not my computer but that is in the same network and I have full rights to access it. In case, my address is (192.168.1.200) in this network. So, it seems after i go through 192.168.1.4, it use my own address instead of the real one, so the file cannot found...how to solve it?..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The textbox field's name (not id) is what should identify the value posted.